# Unclear how to import from a module defined in another target (python bazel)

Tags: python, bazel

I have the following file structure

```
.
├── bedrock
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── bedrock
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── main.py
└── boilerplate
    ├── BUILD
    └── main.py
```

```py
# boilerplate/BUILD
py_binary(
  name = "main",
  main="main.py",
  srcs = ["main.py","//bedrock:main"],
)
```

And

```py
# bedrock/BUILD
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
py_library(
  name = "main",
  srcs = glob(["**/*.py"]),
)
```

And

```py
# bedrock/bedrock/main.py
def some_method():
  return "some_value"
```

How do I access `some_method` in `boilerplate/main.py`????

Bazel python documentation (and actually, any kind of documentation) is VERY POOR!

Answer (score 0):

It would typically be `from bedrock.bedrock import main`.

One note is that `srcs = ["main.py","//bedrock:main"]` is not usually correct, targets don't usually depend on sources from other packages. This would usually be in `deps` as `deps = [//bedrock:main]`

Example:

`bedrock/BUILD`:

```
py_library(
  name = "main",
  srcs = ["bedrock/main.py"],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

`bedrock/bedrock/main.py`:

```
def bedrock_function():
  return "bedrock"
```

`boilerplate/BUILD`:

```
py_binary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = ["main.py"],
  deps = ["//bedrock:main"],
)
```

`boilerplate/main.py`:

```
from bedrock.bedrock import main

print(main.bedrock_function())
```

```
$ bazel run //boilerplate:main
INFO: Analyzed target //boilerplate:main (72 packages loaded, 597 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //boilerplate:main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/boilerplate/main
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.272s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 6 processes: 6 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/boilerplate/main
bedrock
```

This is the same as running `boilerplate/main.py` running from the workspace root with the `PYTHONPATH` set to the current directory:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python boilerplate/main.py
bedrock
```